# Merging two objects and override empty attributes (PHP)

Tags: php, oop

I have two objects and the way our finder function works (I have to call it twice... 1 to get the config key, value i.e. non multilanguage stuff. And the second call to get the multilanguage stuff) makes them look like this:

```
[config] => Array
    (
        [cfg] => Config_Model Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [key] => system.default.main_color
                [value] => #FF7C11
                [deleted] => 0
            )

        [help] => Config_Model Object
            (
                [id] => 
                [key] => 
                [value] => 
                [id_config] => 2
                [name] => Hauptfarbe
                [help] => Die Hauptfarbe Ihres CIs. Der Adminbereich erscheint in dieser Farbe.
                [id_lang] => 1
            )

    )
```

I want to compine these two objects into one. The code, that gets the stuff looks like this:

```
public static function get($key)
{
  $config['cfg'] = self::find(array('key' => $key), TRUE);
  $config['help'] = self::findInTable(array(
    'id_lang' => Language_Model::getDefaultLanguage(), 
    'id_config' => $config['cfg']->getId()
  ), self::dbTranslationTable, TRUE);
  return $config;
  // return (object) array_merge((array) $config['cfg'], (array) $config['help']);
}
```

You can tell by the commented return command, that I tried using array_merge(). The problem with that is, that the empty attributes from [help] override the attributes from [cfg], so they are empty again:

```
[config] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 
        [key] => 
        [value] => 
        [deleted] => 0
        [id_config] => 2
        [name] => Hauptfarbe
        [help] => Die Hauptfarbe Ihres CIs. Der Adminbereich erscheint in dieser Farbe.
        [id_lang] => 1
    )
```

Whereas it should rather look like this:

```
[config] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [key] => system.defalult.main_color
        [value] => #FF7C11
        [deleted] => 0
        [id_config] => 2
        [name] => Hauptfarbe
        [help] => Die Hauptfarbe Ihres CIs. Der Adminbereich erscheint in dieser Farbe.
        [id_lang] => 1
    )
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter out empty values from your second array, and then merge only what's left onto the first array.

The simplest solution would be:

```
$config['help'] = array_filter((array) $config['help']);
return (object) array_merge((array) $config['cfg'], (array) $config['help']);
```

This uses the default behaviour of [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), which just checks whether the values evaluate to `false`. This will remove empty strings, NULL values, or even the number zero.

A safer solution will actually check for empty strings, like this:

```
$config['help'] = array_filter((array) $config['help'], function($val) {
    return (string) $val != '';
});
return (object) array_merge((array) $config['cfg'], (array) $config['help']);
```

Comment: Hmmm, if I try that, it completely removes $config['help'] from the final array...

Comment: Double-check that you're running my latest code - I had a backwards comparison in my first version and have since edited it.

Comment: Copypasted the latest edit, still it removes everything from $config['help']

Comment: I forgot to cast to array - Try now.

Comment: Yep, that worked! Thank you, gonna mark this as the answer, since it seems like a safer approach than mine! Again thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Silly me... I really should try EVERYTHING before asking a question. Sorry for the unnecessary use of space... The order of how you pass the variables to array_merge() matters! I just turned it around, now it looks like this:

```
return (object) array_merge((array) $config['help'], (array) $config['cfg']);
```

And TA-DA! The array looks just like I wanted.

Comment: Do you ever have empty values in the first array that you don't want to overwrite the values from the second?

Comment: array_filter on the second argument should take care of that.

Comment: The key question that should determine which order you put them in is what should happen if the value is defined in both arrays? Whichever value should be kept is the array that should appear second.

Comment: I don't think that's gonna be the case. For stuff that is multilanguage we always have to tables. 1 Table holds stuff like IDs, numbers, non-multilanguage stuff like the config_keys. And the second table points to that table with a id_<name> and to the language table with the id_lang... There never are the same keys in the two arrays.

Comment: `return (object)((array)$cfg["config"]+(array)$cfg["help"]);` should work as well